# Make "import/extensions" require the .js extension in a Node.js TypeScript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

First of all, some facts:

- Node.js requires that all local `import`s include the imported module's extension (e.g. `import hello from './hello.js'`, not `import hello from './hello'`).
- TypeScript will compile `import`s with or without the `.js` extension, which means a missing `.js` extension is a runtime error.
- TypeScript doesn't transform `import`s to add the `.js` extension or convert `.ts` to `.js`.

In my Node.js project, I want to make missing a missing `.js` extension be a build-time error using the `import/extensions` ESLint rule. However, when I enable this rule using the following configuration:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {},
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/extensions": ["error", "ignorePackages"]
  }
}
```

running `eslint` gives me the following error:

```
/sandbox/src/index.ts
  1:19  error  Missing file extension "ts" for "./hello.js"  import/extensions
```

Source files:

```
// index.ts
import hello from "./hello.js";

hello();
```

```
// hello.ts
export default function hello() {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-germain-13glp7

Comment: Is compiling to commonjs or <ES6 an option for you?

Comment: @SebastianSalletmayer that's a last resort, as is using a bundler. Anyway, I solved the problem. See my answer.

Comment: https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-canonical#require-extension will do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this with the following config:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "import/extensions": ["error", "ignorePackages"],
    "import/no-unresolved": "off"
  }
}
```

The main thing is to disable the `"import/no-unresolved"` rule and remove `"settings"."import/resolver"."node"`. (`"import/no-unresolved"` is redundant as unresolved imports are resolved at the compilation stage.) Other items removed here were already being added as a result of extending the `@typescript-eslint` plugins.

Comment: I'm still getting ```Missing file extension "ts" for "./admin.js"``` when importing ```admin.ts``` as ```import { app } from './admin.js';```.

Answer (score 1):

I found an eslint plugin that can fix missing `.js` extensions for imports in `.ts` files, instead of just showing an error:

https://github.com/AlexSergey/eslint-plugin-file-extension-in-import-ts
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-file-extension-in-import-ts

Install:

```bash
npm i -D eslint-plugin-file-extension-in-import-ts
```

Add to `.eslintrc` file:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    "file-extension-in-import-ts"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "file-extension-in-import-ts/file-extension-in-import-ts": "error"
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** I ran into an issue similar to https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1292 when using this package, and it will incorrectly try to add `.js` extensions on these paths when fixing automatically.

Comment: Consider this as an alternative https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-canonical#require-extension

Answer (score 0):

You could try `ts-add-js-extension` package to append `.js` extension to the transpiled JavaScript files. After you install you can do

```bash
ts-add-js-extension add --dir={your-transpiled-outdir}
```

Comment: or use https://github.com/Zoltu/typescript-transformer-append-js-extension